# LexikJWT get token

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, token, fosuserbundle

I'm using symfony2 for a website. I also using Fosuser and LexikJWT to connect by a webservice. I read the documentation of LexikJWT but it's doesn't work.

## parameters.yml

```
jwt_private_key_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/private.pem   # ssh private key path
    jwt_public_key_path:  %kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/public.pem    # ssh public key path
    jwt_key_pass_phrase:  'mypass'                               # ssh key pass phrase
    jwt_token_ttl:        86400
```

## routing.yml

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
admin:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    prefix: /
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

## config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User

    registration:

        confirmation:
            enabled: true
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.default
    lexik_jwt_authentication:
       private_key_path: %jwt_private_key_path%
       public_key_path:  %jwt_public_key_path%
       pass_phrase:      %jwt_key_pass_phrase%
       token_ttl:        %jwt_token_ttl%
```

## security.yml

security:

```
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        main:
            anonymous: true
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                 provider: fos_userbundle
                 #csrf_provider: fos_user.user_provider.username
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
#            http_basic:
#                realm: "REST Service Realm"
#                provider: fos_userbundle



        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            #provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                login_path:               fos_user_security_login
                check_path:               fos_user_security_check
                username_parameter:       username
                password_parameter:       password
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api/.*
            stateless: true
            lexik_jwt: ~
            provider: fos_userbundle



#        default:
#            pattern: ^/
#            http_basic:
#               realm: "REST Service Realm"
#               provider: fos_userbundle
#            logout:       true


            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: ROLE_API }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

To get token, i put on the terminal :

```
curl -X POST -d '{"username": "xxxx", "password": "xxxxx"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://myhost:8888/api/login_check
```

and it returns :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://myhost:8888/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://myhost:8888/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://myhost:8888/login">http://myhost:8888/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

But i want a json response like :

```
{
   "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MzQ3Mjc1MzYsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoia29ybGVvbiIsImlhdCI6IjE0MzQ2NDExMzYifQ.nh0L_wuJy6ZKIQWh6OrW5hdLkviTs1_bau2GqYdDCB0Yqy_RplkFghsuqMpsFls8zKEErdX5TYCOR7muX0aQvQxGQ4mpBkvMDhJ4-pE4ct2obeMTr_s4X8nC00rBYPofrOONUOR4utbzvbd4d2xT_tj4TdR_0tsr91Y7VskCRFnoXAnNT-qQb7ci7HIBTbutb9zVStOFejrb4aLbr7Fl4byeIEYgp2Gd7gY"
}
```

I don't understand ... anyone can help me ?

Thanks !!

EDIT : I saw the dev log and the error is :

```
Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated
```